# setting for child category on single.php wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

can any one help me or translate what I want in php:
 I need php code like that:
 If child categories posts from the parent category number (1) {

will include templatepath'/single-Arabic.php

}
 else if child categories posts from the parent category number (2) {

will include templatepath'/single-English.php

}
 best regards

Answer (score 0):

It's better to check for category name rather than category ID. So lets say you have two categories, "fruit" and "meat", then in your `single.php` just after the `get_header();` call, add these lines:

```
if(has_term('fruit', 'category', $post)) get_template_part('single', 'fruit');
else if(has_term('meat', 'category', $post)) get_template_part('single', 'meat');
// else...
```

This will work if you've created the files `single-fruit.php` and `single-meat.php`

More here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part

Comment: sorry not work, you I think you  don't understand me:

Comment: sorry not work, I think you  don't understand, let me explain:

I've parent category (Arabic)  and parent category (English), any category from those have four categories and any category from four categories have posts...
so I need the posts from child category of English parent category use different header and footer also for Arabic parent category use different header and footer

Comment: the header and footer are meant to be shared across the whole site. what  do you need to do differently in the header and footer? are you sure you can't make the changes using CSS? failing that, why don't you move the header and footer code into the templates? then you could use my code above.

Comment: the headers and footers has different list item text, any content created from page admin screen using different template of page attribute panel..
so I need something like page attribute panel to make different header for English and Arabic post category...
I think not found like template choose in page attribute panel for category and posts..
so I've thought about it and get answer to make English category that containing categories and categories containing posts to usin for header English, and same words for Arabic categories

Comment: i've created single-ar.php for header Arabic and single-en.php for header English.. so whats need to write in single.php to connect Arabic category subcategories posts to connect with single-ar.php, same words for English..
sorry for my english

Comment: Please re-read my comment. The header and footers in WordPress are **meant to be the same across your whole site**. Why don't you move the links into the page template files instead of being in the header and footer?

Comment: headers and footers not have links only its containing different image

Comment: so is all you want to do have a different image depending on English/Arabic?

Comment: can you provide a link to your site?

Comment: the different in headers and footers images and <a> tag text and Arabic header have div container for direction rtl

Comment: all I need,  post page for English and past page for arabic

Comment: This is normally handled using a plugin like WPML (https://wpml.org/). But you have to pay for it. If you're looking for a free option then have you tried looking at the classes that are attached to the body element of each page, and then changing the appearance of those pages by targeting those classes in CSS?

Comment: Hi Peter, did you get anywhere with this? If my solution helped can you please accept it?

Answer (score 0):

here is the function to get top parent category.

let suppose you have category

> 1 . English  
>    -- sub 1 English category 
>    -- sub 2 English
>   category
>
> 2 . Arabic  
>    -- sub 1 Arabic  category 
>    -- sub 2 Arabic 
>   category

and you are on the post page where it say current category `sub 2 English`
then you call function

```
$Parent = strtolower(get_top_category());
```

it will return top category name which is **`English`**, after that condition will check if category is English then `include 'single-English.php'`

**vice versa for Arabic.**

```
function get_top_category() {

    $category = get_the_category();
    $cat_tree = get_category_parents($category[0]->term_id, FALSE, ':', TRUE);
    $top_cat = split(':',$cat_tree);
    return $parent = $top_cat[0];
}

echo '<pre>';print_r(get_top_category());echo '</pre>';

$Parent = strtolower(get_top_category());
if($Parent == "english") {
    include 'templatepath/single-English.php';
}
else if($Parent == "arabic") {
    include 'templatepath/single-Arabic.php';
}
```

Comment: no, not working, when I click to the post...show me English word only and also on arabic

Comment: I need to show the posts from the sub category, 
could you try with me to get the fix for this problem

Comment: please update your question with php code from where it is running, add your single.php code in question

Comment: there is my old single.php code
<?php 

$post = $wp_query->post;

if (in_category('24')) {

  include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/single-ar.php'); 

}

elseif (in_category('25')) {

  include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/single-en.php'); 

}


?>
number 24 is the number of category Arabic and 
number 25 is the number of category English ,  I need to show the post from subcategory of category English same that with arabic

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about whether the post is in a child category or not. The only thing you care about is whether it **has** a particular category (English or Arabic). So no need to use 4 lines of code to check the parent category. Just check if **this** post is in that category - `if(has_term('english', 'category', $post))`